# Git tags have disappeared

Tags: git, github, versioning

I checked out a new branch and named it `v0.1.1`. I changed the version in `package.json` to match, and I also used `git tag` to create some tags. I eventually merged this branch into master, thinking the tagging / versioning activity would "propagate" to `master` somehow. Not only did they not propagate, they seem to have disappeared, as if I did nothing at all.

What are the steps to:

- locally **identify a commit as a version of interest** (whether it be just a useful baseline or an actual release - does the distinction matter? Are those 2 separate commands?)
- ensure that any such versioning info is immediately **identifiable in GitHub** after a push?
- if the above process is wrong (i.e. if there's a proper/better way to approach all this).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several points about tags:

#### Tags need to be pushed to a remote explicitly

`git push` will not push your tags to a remote. Instead, you need to run (assuming your remote is called `origin`):

```sh
git push origin --tags
```

to push all your tags or:

```sh
git push origin <tag>
```

to push a single tag.

So if you want a commit to be easily identifiable on GitHub, you will have to ensure to push the corresponding tag (or all tags).

#### Your tags have not disappeared: they are simply on another branch

Your tags have not disappeared: they are on your branch `v0.1.1`.

If you run `git log` from your branch `master`, you won't see them. But if you checkout `v0.1.1`, *then* run `git log`, you will see them.

Another option is to run `git log --all`: this shows all your branches (even the ones that aren't part of the history of the branch you are on) as well as all the stashes and tags.

You can list all your tags with:

```sh
git tag
```

And you can checkout a tag with:

```sh
git checkout <tag>
```

#### Tags are the proper way to easily identify a commit

To identify a commit of interest, tags are indeed the right approach. So your workflow was good.

Comment: Or just `git checkout [name-of-the-tag]`

Answer (score 4):

A tag is nothing but a permanent name for one particular commit. For example:

```
A -- B -- C -- D <--(somebranch, HEAD)
```

Let's say I now tag commit `D` with the name `myTag`. Then I keep working:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F <--(somebranch, HEAD)
               |
             myTag
```

No matter what, from now on, `myTag` refers to commit `D`. Not only that, it will help to *preserve* commit `D` for all time, because whatever has a name or is pointed to by something with a name cannot die.

And that's basically the whole story. You can do anything you like with whatever branch I may have been working on at the time; it won't matter. You can merge the branch. You can delete the branch. You can rename the branch. It makes no difference. `myTag` and `D` will always be `myTag` and `D`, forever, and that's all they will ever be.

Comment: I can only accept one answer unfortunately but both yours and the other answer explain the 2 concepts i was missing. 1) tags dont propagate like that and 2) you have to explicitly push them. thx!

Comment: Yes, I agree, the fact that tags do not _automatically_ travel with the push to the remote can be surprising. So that's the info you really needed. I was just trying to deal with the misconception about the tag disappearing.